# Servo or motor with manual control

Tags: mechanical

I am searching for a servo or motor with the ability to
easy manually controlling (turning) when power off.
What is the mechanism recommend to use?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: please explain how your question is about the Arduino ....... `arduino-uno` and `arduino-nano` tags do not count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motor that has no gearbox will be easier to manually turn when it is not powered.
Now, I don't know what you categorize as "easy" but this info will give you a starting point.

And I don't get why the use of the "arduino-nano" and "arduino-uno" tag